# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS reboot instead of shuting down

Tags: shutdown, reboot

Even when it is similar to previous questions my pc can enter into stand by, suspend or reboot. The problem is when trying to shut down it seems to be turn off a second and then start again. I have to log into windows and then shut down form there.

Its weird because a week ago (maybe two) everything were working perfectly I remember running a software update during this period but nothing important only chrome updates or things like that.

This is my lap info:

HP Pavilion Laptop 15-eh3xxx
AMD® Ryzen 7 7730u with radeon graphics × 16
RENOIR (renoir, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.49, 6.2.0-36-generic)
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Dual boot W11

Command line:
shutdown -h now (That only reboot the pc as mentioned before)
Using the "natural" way clicking where the battery icon is, then select from the dropdown menu "shut down" and this reboot the pc, no powered off.

UNBELIEVABLE!:
Yesterday's software update (11/15/2023) left the computer working 100% properly it did a clean & smooth shut down. No reboot

Today's software update (11/16/2023) let the computer unable to shut down again, (sad again) it reboot instead of powere off.

What I could see in a glance from yesterdat's update vs Today's update was that yesterday's update automatically uncheck Intel patches (Im running on AMD RYZEN) and on the other hand today's update included Intel's patches in the "Ubuntu base" update.

How can I take a look of what was updated last two days in order to have a clue? Thanx in advance

Comment: How are you shutting down Ubuntu? What command or menu are you using? Please [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1492383/edit) your question and add this information.